# Cache on leaflet tileLayer while using mapbox style

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using mapbox custom style as tileLayer through leaflet. If I update the existing custom style from mapbox, then the changes(example: changing colors) are not visible on the map. It is visible only when I zoomed in or zoomed out. I guess it is cached.

My code:

```
L.tileLayer(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ffaudun/ckoydiulo2f9d17o1puc4c30f/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + L.mapbox.accessToken, {
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        }).addTo(map);
```

I have also tried below solution **without any success**:

```
var genRandom = function() {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * 100000 ) + 1;
    };

L.tileLayer(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ffaudun/ckoydiulo2f9d17o1puc4c30f/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?{randomNumber}&access_token=' + L.mapbox.accessToken, {
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            randomNumber: genRandom,
        }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, we must check if it client cache (browser) by disabling cache from network tab in DevTools(F12),
then you can avoid browser cache by adding a new parameter at the end of the map URL for example (url.com?anyparameter=anyvalue) and change the value after any change in mapbox